# Kubernetes HPA with custom metrics in 1.5

Tags: kubernetes

I have k8s v1.5 installad, I tried to following  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/ to implement HPA with custom metric.

In the page above, it said "`--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-use-rest-clients` flag on the controller manager set to true. " but while I set it, the controller manager cannot be started because this flag is not support.

So how can I find any guide for k8s v1.5?

Here is my k8s version information:

```
[bow@devvm13 ~]$ kubectl version 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.1", GitCommit:"82450d03cb057bab0950214ef122b67c83fb11df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-14T00:57:05Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.0", GitCommit:"58b7c16a52c03e4a849874602be42ee71afdcab1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-12T23:31:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 1):

--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-use-rest-clients is supported after 1.6. 
 you can refer https://medium.com/@marko.luksa/kubernetes-autoscaling-based-on-custom-metrics-without-using-a-host-port-b783ed6241ac as an example.

Comment: I tried it, it does not work. the difference is, the page used minikub, I used the standard version. I set all possible options in kubelet:    # ps -ef | grep kubelet
root     20168     1  4 15:07 ?        00:10:11 /usr/bin/kubelet --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --require-kubeconfig=true --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cluster-dns=10.96.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --enable-custom-metrics=true EnableCustomMetrics=true ENABLE_CUSTOM_METRICS=true